# How to describe destructured props in React in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My component:

```
interface Props {
  label: string;
}

const FormDate: React.FC<Props> = ({ label, ...props }) => {
```

This is how I use that component:

```
<FormDate label="Data" name="date" type="date" />
```

How can i describe `...props` in Typescript if I don't want to destruct "name" and "type" separately as I did with "label"?

Comment: Depends on where are those props placed. Is it a div tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add them to the interface with the correct type and use them:

```js
interface Props {
  label: string;
  name: string;
  type: string; // or here give a more precise type like 'date'
}

const FormDate: React.FC<Props> = ({ label, ...props }) => {
```

Comment: Oh. It was that easy. Thank you

Comment: @Mimoid Ahah no issue ;) Please don't forget to `validate` the answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

In case you have an unknown amount of properties, you can also use a [string index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html):

```
interface Props {
  label: string;
  [propName: string]: any;
}
```

Now you can pass any amount of properties without Typescript complaining.

Comment: Correct but what's the goal of using TypeScript in this case?

Comment: Make your coworkers happy and reduce the impact on your personal productivity ;-)

Comment: How can they be happy? If you should use a tool, use it the right way.

Comment: In a perfect world, yes.